# Shape with a directrix that's not a straight line

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So in my earlier query about how to find the closest point on $-x^2-1$ to a given point, my end goal was not made clear but I was attempting to find the equation for the shape that only contained points equally as close to $(0,1)$ as they were to the closest point on $-x^2-1$. In other words, what shape would form if the same rules were applied as to make a parabola, but with the directrix being a parabola instead of a straight line. However, despite me finding three explicit formulas, I could not simplify the equation enough to find the direct function that would satisfy those conditions. I was, however, able to make a GeoGebra app that could take any focus and any function as the directrix and, with a lot of scrolling sliders, eventually get a vague outline for what the shape looks like. I also tried a logarithmic and exponential function, and the results were quite interesting looking but I would really want to see the relation that forms them. I am interested to see if anyone could find out what the equation for the parabola shaped directrix looks like and also see some other functions as the directrix.

Comment: If I didn't make any mistake, the locus is a branch of following quintic curve in upper half-plane:
$$\small 64y^5-128y^4-8x^2y^3+352y^3+252x^2y^2-288y^2+378x^2y+324y-27x^4-27x^2 = 0$$
This curve seems to have 3 branches, one in $3$-rd and another in $4$-th quadrant.
Just type above equation into GeoGebra to see what it looks like.

Comment: That is incredibly cool. What process did you use to find that equation

Comment: Write down the set of equation for $(x,y)$ and  $(u,v)$ (the closest point to $(x,y)$ on the parabola $v + u^2 + 1 - 0$). Throw the set of equations to a CAS to eliminate $u,v$  (I use the command resultant in maxima).